# How to do Classification using svmLinear carat package and not Regression

Tags: r, classification, svm

I have a dataset which has labels as y = 1, 2, 3, 4. I wish to do classification by svmLinear method using the train() function available in the carat package in R. Here is sample code which I wrote. I used the default trainControl function.

```
trainer = train(y~., data=traindf, method="svmLinear")
predicted = predict(trainer, testdf)
```

But it appears like, it is performing regression rather then classification as the predicted values are not discreete values of 1,2,3,4. It has decimal values as well.
How can I run multi-class classification using svmLinear method of train function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of what class is `y`? Unless there's a parameter from the `svmLinear` package you can specify the type of output, `y` will be analysed and a model is build regarding its type. At least this is how it works with other supervised methods that Caret as wrapped (such as `nnet`).

In short, fix this by ensuring that `y` is of type `factor` by:

```
trainer = train(as.factor(y) ~ . -y, data=traindf, method="svmLinear")
```

**Update:**
I can't find the documentation to the specific package Caret is wrapping for `linearSVM` but you should also be able to specify a type in the arguments. Such as `type=C-svc`

This may also be the case with `predict()` where you can also specify a type. e.g. `type = c('prob', 'class')`